# Cannot read property 'env' of undefined while building nativescript-vue project

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

When I building nativescript-vue application using "tns build android --bundle" it shows

Project successfully prepared (android)

Executing after-prepare hook from D:\Downloads\User\Desktop\App\hooks\after-prepare\nativescript-dev-webpack.js

Cannot read property 'env' of undefined

Comment: You should look at this : https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/4751